# React context state updates are always one step behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read questions with similar titles and they have not solved my problem.

I have an API call whose result needs to be shared amongst several components. The parent component makes the call and React's context is used to share it amongst the child components:

**MainPage.js:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { VideoPlayer } from "../components/VideoPlayer";
import VideoContext from "../components/VideoContext";


export default function Watch() {
    const [video, setVideo] = useState({});
    const { videoHash } = useParams();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        getVideo();
    }, [videoHash]);

    const getVideo = async () => {
        if(videoHash) {
            const res = await getVideoFromApi();
            setIsLoading(false);
            // The first time this runs nothing happens, the video can't be played
            // The second time it runs (i.e. when the URL/videoHash changes) it updates 
            // but it shows the video from the first run
            setVideo(res.video);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading ? (
                <div>Loading...</div>
            ) : (
                <VideoContext.Provider value={{ video, setVideo }}>
                    <VideoPlayer videoHash={videoHash} />
                </VideoContext.Provider>
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

**VideoPlayer.js:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import VideoContext from "./VideoContext";
import styles from "./VideoPlayer.module.css";

export function VideoPlayer({ videoHash }) {
    const { video, setVideo } = useContext(VideoContext);
    const [forceRender, setforceRender] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        // I tried adding this to no effect
        setforceRender(!forceRender);
    }, [videoHash]);

    return (
        <video controls className={styles["video-player"]}>
            <source src={video.VideoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
                Sorry, your browser does not support embedded videos.
        </video>
    );
}
```

**VideoContext.js**:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export default createContext({
    video: {}, 
    setVideo: () => {}
});
```

It works when the page loads, but when my `Link` components change the `videoHash` property the new video loads (I can see when I `console.log()` the API call) but it does not update in the video player.

The *second* time a link is clicked and the `videoHash` param is changed, the video displays but it's for the previous video.

Comment: Working on this but having trouble transferring it over: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-shape-rcth6?file=/src/Watch.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-lake-k4i8n?file=/src/VideoPlayer.js

Unless I'm missing something, I think the VideoPlayer would be all right just behaving as a functional component without any hooks for state, that could be handled by Watch. When you click on a link to another route that will point to watch, the videoHash will change

#### VideoPlayer.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export function VideoPlayer({ videoHash }) {
  // const { video, setVideo } = useContext(VideoContext);
  // const [forceRender, setforceRender] = useState(true);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   // I tried adding this to no effect
  //   setforceRender(!forceRender);
  // }, [videoHash]);
  // console.log(video);
  // Am I missi
  return (
    <div>
      Am I missing something or could you just use your videoHash: {videoHash},
      here?
      <Link to="/watch/a">Previous</Link>
      <Link to="/watch/c">Next</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Watch.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { VideoPlayer } from "./VideoPlayer";
import VideoContext from "./VideoContext";

export default function Watch() {
  const [video, setVideo] = useState({});
  const { videoHash } = useParams();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const getVideo = useCallback(async () => {
    if (videoHash) {
      const res = await getVideoFromApi();
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setVideo(res);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [videoHash]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    getVideo();
  }, [getVideo]);

  const getVideoFromApi = async () => {
    const videoArray = ["A", "B", "C"];
    const randomItem =
      videoArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * videoArray.length)];
    return Promise.resolve(randomItem);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <VideoContext.Provider value={{ video, setVideo }}>
          <VideoPlayer videoHash={videoHash} />
        </VideoContext.Provider>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

#### VideoContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export default createContext({
  video: "",
  setVideo: () => {}
});
```

I added a timeout so you can see the loading part work as well. Let me know if there's something I'm missing about what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for this - it needed fresh eyes. You are correct; VideoPlayer did not need to be anything other than a simple view component. I did not use Context originally so was converting my old logic to use Context and got muddled in the process. In the parent component that houses the VideoPlayer I have my loading spinner based on an `isLoading` state variable; that changing from true/false forces the re-render after a video loads.